# Notification BroadcastReceiver Not Working In Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

I have a notification and am trying to run a method in an activity when a specific button in the notification is pressed. I am creating the broadcastReceiver in onCreate:

```
    //broadcast receiver stuff
    broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Code to run
            if (intent.getAction().equals("stop")){
                StartButtonClick();
            }
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("stop"));
```

Then I create the notification in the same activity (not in onCreate though):

```
private void ShowNotification(){
    //add intent for app to resume when notification is clicked
    PendingIntent reopenAppIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //add intent for app to stop service when stop button in notification is clicked
    //this is the intent I am creating for the notification button
    Intent stopIntent = new Intent("stop");
    PendingIntent stopPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, stopIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //create notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_1_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Messaging in progress")
            .setContentText("User is late")
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_message)
            .setContentIntent(reopenAppIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_message, "Stop", stopPendingIntent); //here I am adding the intent for the butt that I want to activate the broadcastReceiver
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification.build());
}
```

When I click the button in the notification, nothing happens. I even put a break point on the broadcastReceiver's if-statement and nothing ever happens on the button press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
PendingIntent stopPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, stopIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

instead of

```
PendingIntent stopPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, stopIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```